# getting an error like Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I am trying to set the state in request data method for a string variable like this below

```
const ViewChangeRequest = () => {
      const [requestStageValue, setRequestStage] = useState('');
      const { data: requestData, loading: requestDataLoading, error: requestDataError } = 
        useQuery(GET_SPECIFICREQUEST, {
          variables: { requestinputs: { id } },
      });

      if (requestData != null) {
setRequestStage(requestData.allRequests[0].requestStage.name); // getting error at here 
requestData.allRequests.map((code) => {
    requestDatasource.push({
        id: code.id,
        section: code.masterSection.name,
        createdBy: code.createdBy,
        type: code.requestType.name,
        status: code.requestStage.name,
        createat: code.createdAt,
    });
    return null;
  });
 } 
};
export default withRouter(ViewChangeRequest);
```

Depends upon the requeststage value, i am verifying conditions like this below

```
 if (requestStageValue === 'Request Submitted') {
stepNumber = 0;
} else if (requestStageValue === 'In Review') {
stepNumber = 1;
} else {
stepNumber = 2;
}
```

I am getting an error `Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop` at this line `setRequestStage(requestData.allRequests[0].requestStage.name)`

I am not able to understand where i am doing wrong while setting up the state to string varaiable.

Could any one please help me out from this situation that would be very grateful to me, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you're running `setRequestStage` in the function. This will trigger a state update, which means the functions runs again (since state updates trigger re-renders), which means `setRequestStage` runs again, which means the state updates again, so functions runs again etc. etc. - infinite loop.

If you're wanting to set an initial state based on `requestData`, do it when declaring it in `useState`:

```
const [requestStageValue, setRequestStage] = useState(
    requestData !== null ? requestData.allRequests[0].requestStage.name : ''
);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. So, do you want me remove this line inside function `setRequestStage(requestData.allRequests[0].requestStage.name);`

Comment: @EnigmaState yes remove that and add the initial value setting inside the `useState(...)` call as in my answer

Comment: i removed that but getting one more error like `Cannot read property 'allRequests' of undefined`

Comment: if i check like this `(requestData !== null && requestData !== undefined)` i am not getting any error and not able to set any value for requeststage .. its coming as null.. this value i need to set in rendering as well

Comment: @EnigmaState well I dunno what your `requestData` object is like so it's hard to know how to properly check it. You'll have to log it and maybe use `typeof` to see what it actually is before (and after) it's defined

Comment: i am  able to see the values for `requestData.allRequests[0].requestStage.name` but some how the usestate is not setting up and getting empty value for `requestStageValue`